# Using Python to reduce the two lines of data in a file to create a new file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to use python to reduce the two lines of data in a file to create a new file. I use pandas and numpy for processing, but the processing time of pandas is very long,even need a few hours, while numpy can be two or three minutes, a total of more than 1 million data, 
as part of the data:

```
33,Jogging,49105962326000,-0.6946377,12.680544,0.50395286;
33,Jogging,49106062271000,5.012288,11.264028,0.95342433;
33,Jogging,49106112167000,4.903325,10.882658,-0.08172209;
```

My pandas code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
time1 = time.time()
file = open('WISDM_ar_v1.1_raw.txt','r')
dataset = file.readlines()
list1 = []
for i in range(len(dataset)-1):
    dataset[i] = dataset[i].rstrip('\n')
    dataset[i] = dataset[i].rstrip(';')
    dataset[i] = dataset[i].split(",")
    if len(dataset[i])==6:
        #list1为处理后的数据
        list1.append(dataset[i])

array1 = np.array(list1)
#newline两行之间按什么分割 delimiter列之间按什么分割
np.savetxt("aa.txt", array1,  fmt="%s",newline='\r\n', delimiter=",")
column_names = ['user-id', 'activity', 'timestamp', 'x-axis', 'y-axis', 'z-axis']
dataset1 = pd.read_csv('aa.txt',names=column_names, header=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
for i in range(0,len(dataset1)-1):
    data = dataset1.loc[[i]]
    if dataset1.loc[i+1, 'activity']==dataset1.loc[i,'activity']:
        data.loc[i,'user-id'] = dataset1.loc[i,'user-id']
        data.loc[i,'x-axis'] = dataset1.loc[i+1,'x-axis']-dataset1.loc[i,'x-axis']
        data.loc[i,'y-axis'] = dataset1.loc[i+1,'y-axis'] - dataset1.loc[i,'y-axis']
        data.loc[i,'z-axis'] = dataset1.loc[i+1,'z-axis'] - dataset1.loc[i,'z-axis']
        df1 = df1.append(data, ignore_index=True)
df1.to_csv('new_data.txt', mode='a',sep=',', header=False, index=False)
```

I want to know why this is the case. Is there any mistake in the pandas code I wrote？ Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you give an example file, the logic to merge lines and an expected output?

Comment: such as the first two row:

Comment: such as the first two row                             33,Jogging,49105962326000,-0.6946377,12.680544,0.50395286;
33,Jogging,49106062271000,5.012288,11.264028,0.95342433;              The output file's data is 33,Jogging,99945000.0,5.7069257,-1.4165159999999997,0.4494714700000001         If the two lines of data are the same activity, perform a subtractive operation.The latter four column of  output data  is generate by second row reduce first row.